# Как имитировать нажатие на submit?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть форма. В ней два input'a. один для выбора фалов другой submit. Вот как сделать так что после того как пользователь выбрал файл отправка формы началась автоматически без нажатия на submit

Comment: Лучше не надо так, а вдруг пользователь выбрал случайно не тот файл?

Comment: моя_голая_жена_hd.avi

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="file" onChange="document.getElementById('form').submit();">
```

или как то так с помощью jquery, кто любит мух отделять от котлет:

```
$("#file").change(function () {
formname.submit();
}).change();
```

Comment: Можно в onChange написать this.ParentNode.submit();

Comment: Спасибо! Уже сделал точно так же.